# How to convert single row of a dataframe into a String in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My dataframe which was created by reading a RDBMS table, has one column and only one value in it:

```
val sourceCols = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", hiveMetaConURL)
                                               .option("dbtable", "(select source_columns from base.spe_tab where tablename='base.forecast') as sCols")
                                               .option("user", metaUserName)
                                               .option("password", metaPassword)
                                               .load()
```

I tried it convert it to a String in the below way:

```
val sourceColDataTypes = sourceCols.rdd.map(_.mkString(",")).collect.foreach(println)
```

When I try to print it as:

```
sourceColDataTypes.foreach(println)
```

I don't see the content, instead I see:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1e489957
```

Is there a way I can use yield of Scala to get the value.
Could anyone let me know how can I convert a row in a DataFrame to a String ?

Comment: you should be doing `sourceCols.rdd.map(_.toSeq.mkString(",")).collect.foreach(println)`

Comment: The foreach(println) is printing the value. But if I assign it to val data:String = sourceCols.rdd.map(_.toSeq.mkString(",")).collect.toString() and print "data", it still prints java.lang.String@30a6984c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value you can use one of the following

```
sourceCols.map(_.getString(0)).collect.foreach(println)
sourceCols.map(_.toSeq.mkString(",")).collect.foreach(println)
```

If you just want to see the data you can use

```
sourceCols.show(false)
```

If you want a single string then you can get it as

```
println(sourceCols.map(_.getString(0)).collect.mkString(","))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this directly on `dataframe`, There is no need to covert to `rdd` at all like this

```
df.select("value").collect.mkString(",").replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
```

**Or**

```
df.map(row=>row.getAs("value").toString).collect.mkString(",")
```